# Union of two denumerable sets is denumerable

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Good night. I have a problem with this exercise:

> Prove that the union of two denumerable sets is denumerable.

Proof:

Be $A,B\subset\mathbb{R}$ where A and B are numerable, in other words $f:\mathbb{N\rightarrow}A$ biyective and $g:\mathbb{N\rightarrow}B$. Be $h:\mathbb{N\rightarrow}A\cup B$ and suppose:

$A=\left\{ a_{1},a_{2},a_{3},...\right\} $

$B=\left\{ b_{1},b_{2},b_{3},...\right\} $

I construct a function biyective such that

$1\rightarrow a_{1}$

$2\rightarrow b_{1}$

$3\rightarrow a_{2}$

$4\rightarrow b_{2}$

$.$

$.$

$.$

Where $h(x)=\begin{cases}
2k+1\rightarrow a_{k}\:k\epsilon\mathbb{N}\\
2k\rightarrow b_{k}\:k\epsilon\mathbb{N}
\end{cases}$

If we see the function $h(x)$ she is $\mathbb{N}$ in other words, $A\cup B$=$\mathbb{N}$ then $h:\mathbb{N\rightarrow}A\cup B$ is biyective.

But i feel my proof is too bad, can someone help me?

Comment: Almost straight from the get-go, you're assuming $A$ and $B$ are disjoint.  This isn't too difficult an issue to amend, but you may want to mention something about it.

Comment: Your function $h$ need not ba bijection; for instance, if $A \cap B \ne \emptyset$ then $h$ is not a bijection. But $h$ is surjective, and this should help you.

Comment: If you want to construct a bijection, you can let $C = B \setminus A$ and note that $A \cup B = A \cup C$, where $A \cup C$ is a disjoint union. Then you can apply your method to $A$ and $C$ (but be careful that $C$ may not be infinite and could even be empty).

Comment: I edited the tags and clarified the title and question to reflect the apparent intent. If the result is not what you intended, please fix accordingly. :-)

Comment: AUB = A∩B U (A-B) U (B-A)
All three are disjoint and subset of A or B or both, hence either empty, finite or infinite. In case of infinite subset of N hence countable. Now you can use your algo using 3n, 3n-1 and 3n-2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The proof is almost correct, and is actually a good way of approaching the problem. One small error is that $h$ is not actually bijective, since you can have $a_i=b_j$ for some $i, j$. However, $h$ is still surjective, which suffices to show the union is countable.

Answer (score 0):

We describe one way to modify your argument.

We assume that both sets are countably infinite. Suppose that we have defined $h(k)$ for every $k\lt n$.

If $n$ is even, let $h(n)=b_j$, where $j$ is the smallest positive integer such that $b_j\ne h(k)$ for any $k\lt n$.

If $n$ is odd, $h(n)=a_j$, where $j$ is the smallest positive integer such that $a_j\ne h(k)$ for any $k\lt n$.

Now one can verify that $h$ is a bijection from $\mathbb{N}$ to $A\cup B$.